# Efficiently Transforming from Spherical Coordinates to Cartesian Coordinates using Eigen

Tags: performance, c++11, eigen

I need to transform the coordinates from spherical to Cartesian space using the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) C++ Library. The following code serves the purpose.

```
 const int size = 1000;
    Eigen::Array<std::pair<float, float>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> direction(size);
    for(int i=0; i<direction.size();i++)
    {
            direction(i).first = (i+10)%360; // some value for this example (denoting the azimuth angle)
            direction(i).second = (i+20)%360; // some value for this example (denoting the elevation angle)

     }

    SSPL::MatrixX<T1> transformedMatrix(3, direction.size());
    for(int i=0; i<transformedMatrix.cols(); i++)
    {
        const T1 azimuthAngle = direction(i).first*M_PI/180;    //converting to radians
        const T1 elevationAngle = direction(i).second*M_PI/180; //converting to radians

        transformedMatrix(0,i) = std::cos(azimuthAngle)*std::cos(elevationAngle);
        transformedMatrix(1,i) = std::sin(azimuthAngle)*std::cos(elevationAngle);
        transformedMatrix(2,i) = std::sin(elevationAngle);
    }
```

I would like to know a better implementation is possible to improve the speed.
I know that Eigen has supporting functions for Geometrical transformations. But I am yet to see a clear example to implement the same.
Is it also possible to vectorize the code to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

You could at least use the vectorized versions of sine/cosine:

```
void dir2vector2(Eigen::Matrix3Xf& out, const Eigen::Array2Xf& in){
    Eigen::Array2Xf sine = sin(in * (M_PI/180));
    Eigen::Array2Xf cosi = cos(in * (M_PI/180));

    out.resize(3, in.cols());

    out << cosi.row(0) * cosi.row(1),
           sine.row(0) * cosi.row(1),
                         sine.row(1);
}
```

There would still be a lot of optimization potential, e.g., calculating both sine and cosine of the same angle could share a lot of computation. And it is technically not necessary to store `sine` and `cosi` explicitly into temporaries (but Eigen is currently not able to automatically re-use common-sub expressions).

Also, the multiplication at the end could be vectorized better, if you store your input and output in row-major format (though the Eigen comma-initializer currently does not well with vectorization, it seems).

Comment: Thanks for the hints on vectorization. I am also interested to see whether some performance improvement is possible by using "Geometry" provided by Eigen!